# sax: how to parse string in order to filter invalid XML character?

Tags: java, sax

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.site.com/1.xml");
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();
parser.parse(url.openStream(),handler);
```

Because 1.xml contains invalid XML characters, parser will throw exceptions, such as *An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1d) was found in the CDATA section.*
but if I read the 1.xml into a String and filter all invalid characters, string can't be the argument of parser.parse() method.
what can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can use `java.io.StringReader` to make a `Reader` from your string, then construct an `org.xml.sax.InputSource` using the `StringReader`.  There's a version of `parse()` that takes an `InputSource` argument.